# Layout Changes when CSS display: changes from none to block after it was changed from block to none

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to show/hide certain options when other options are selected in form elements with Javascript. The issue is the layout gets all out of wack when the options are hidden then un-hidden. Can anyone point me in the direction of why this is happening and how to resolve it? I am not able to add images to this but I will put URLs to the pics.

the id="optionsRow" `DIV` is what is displaying differently once it is unhidden after being hidden.

http://public.pnd-productions.com/images/load.PNG 
http://public.pnd-productions.com/images/hidden.PNG 
http://public.pnd-productions.com/images/unhidden.PNG

```js
function showConditional() {
  if (document.getElementById("conditional").checked === true) {
    document.getElementById("optionsRow").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("optionsRow").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row" id="conditionalCheckRow">
  <div class="col-6 text-right">
    Conditional
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 text-left">
    <input type="checkbox" checked id="conditional" onclick="showConditional()">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="optionsRow">
  <div class="col-6 text-right">
    Options:
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 text-left">
    <select ng-model="opt1" onChange="functionChange()" id="functionType">
      <option value="=QUERY(">QUERY</option>
      <option value="=VLOOKUP(">VLOOKUP</option>
      <option value="=ARRAYFORMULA(">ARRAYFORMULA</option>
      <option value="=ONERROR(">ONERROR</option>
      <option value="=IF(">IF</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's because your row is flex so you need to toggle between flex and none

Comment: I praise you for the knowledge and quick response! Your solution has resolved the issue!

Comment: Another way would be when display optionRow in the javascript set display to inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Auto-layout for flexbox grid columns `col-6` means you can set the width of one column and have the sibling columns automatically resize around it. While `col-lg-6` fill equal width across the row.

```js
function showConditional() {
  if (document.getElementById("conditional").checked === true) {
    document.getElementById("optionsRow").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("optionsRow").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row" id="conditionalCheckRow">
  <div class="col-lg-6">Conditional</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"><input type="checkbox" checked id="conditional" onclick="showConditional()"></div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="optionsRow">
  <div class="col-lg-6">Options:</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <select ng-model="opt1" onChange="functionChange()" id="functionType">
      <option value="=QUERY(">QUERY</option>
      <option value="=VLOOKUP(">VLOOKUP</option>
      <option value="=ARRAYFORMULA(">ARRAYFORMULA</option>
      <option value="=ONERROR(">ONERROR</option>
      <option value="=IF(">IF</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain what you did to fix the problem. [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer.

Comment: @MilesFett thanks for your comment. I appreciate it!